# Compare a local file with its version on a Phabricator/Arcanist revision

Tags: version-control, compare, phabricator, arcanist

I have a revision I have yet to land and would like to compare the local version of a file and the version associated with the latest Arcanist diff on phabricator.

For that matter, it would be interesting to compare the local file with the version associated with a previously landed revision on Phabricator.

It would also be interesting to know if it's possible to compare all files associated with a Phab revision and their local counterparts.  I use git for version control.

How can these be done?

Comment: I think it could be useful to also provide your current version control software (git? Subversion? Mercurial?), even if it may be something universal thanks to Arcanist.

Comment: Question modified to include version control SW.